# Switching between pruned and non-pruned blocksdir ok?

Tags: bitcoind, rescan, datadir

Is it ok to swap the nodes blocksdir upon restart without corrupting sth. cache etc.. I have two blocksdir: one locally pruned `blocks`, the other external with all blocks in `blocks` on usb drive. Id like to swap to external HDD blocksdir to eg rescan etc. 

 like `bitcoin-qt -data-dir=stays_same -blocksdir=changes`